# 'typeRoots' fails to find d.ts declaration files in project

Tags: typescript

```
// tsconfig.json inside "compilerOptions"
    "typeRoots": ["./@types", "./node_modules/@types"],

// {projectRoot}/@types/express/index.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      verifiedAccessToken: string
    }
  }
}
```

In another file with req annotated to Request inside the function parameter, I am still not able to set verifiedAccessToken without a lint error in VsCode:

```
req.verifiedAccessToken = accessToken;
// Property 'verifiedAccessToken' does not exist on 
// type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2339)
```

Anything else that needs to be done for the declaration file to be used?

```
// package.json, relevent deps
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-typescript": "^0.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*" : ["@types/*"]
        }
    }
}`
```

See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217

Answer (score 0):

I followed the accepted answer's link and still had issues. So, for the future searcher, here's [my answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-1078271416) (copy/pasted from my comment in the Github issue):

> @gaurav5430's [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-798964875) got me on the right track!
>
> My original folder layout:
>
> ```
> @types/
>  index.d.ts
> src/
>  index.ts
> package.json
> tsconfig.json
> ```
>
> My `tsconfig.json`:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "baseUrl": "./",
>     "declaration": true,
>     "esModuleInterop": true,
>     "module": "commonjs",
>     "outDir": "dist",
>     "paths": {
>       "*": [
>         "@types/*"
>       ]
>     },
>     "skipLibCheck": true,
>     "sourceMap": true,
>     "strict": true,
>     "target": "es5",
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "node_modules/@types",
>       "@types"
>     ],
>   },
>   "include": [
>     "src/**/*"
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> I was still getting errors and I could not understand why. Turns out, `@types/index.d.ts` should actually be named after the module that doesn't have types. So, for me I had to change: `@types/index.d.ts` to `@types/csv-to-js-parser.d.ts`.
>
> (Contents of that file being `declare module "csv-to-js-parser";`)
>
> FINALLY
>
> Also, this issue is super annoying.