# TypeScript is not picking up my custom type definitions in tsconfig

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm using tsconfig to check my js files. I have my custom type definitions in the `custom_types\custom.d.ts`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./custom_types/", "node_modules/@types/"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

**custom_types/custom.d.ts**

```
declare global {
  const foo: string;

  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      foo: string;
    }
  }
}
export default global;
```

**src/app.js**

```
let bar = foo; // Cannot find name 'foo'.ts(2304)
```

However when I do this in my tsconfig:

```
{
  ...
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "custom_types/custom.d.ts"]
}
```

everything work perfect.
So this makes me think that my `tsconfig` is wrong and `TypesScript` completely ignores this part:

```
"typeRoots": ["./custom_types/", "node_modules/@types/"],
```

What am I'm doing wrong when trying to specify path to the folder with my own custom type definitions?

p.s. `"node_modules/@types/"` is picked up by `TypeScript` properly (everything that is inside `@types` is available to me). However `"./custom_types/"` is ignored.

**UPD:**
Many answers out there are suggestion to do something with `baseUrl` and `paths`. However doing this did nothing for me:

```
 "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@custom_types": ["*", "./custom_types/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["@custom_types/custom.d.ts", "node_modules/@types/"],
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this a while ago and I remember that it was a struggle. They might have changed it in the newer versions of typescript but I haven't tested it out yet. The tsconfig that I have from a while ago looks like:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "./types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

Take a look at the [**include**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#tsconfig-bases) and [**paths**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) settings where I specify the location of my custom type definitions folder. This works in typescript 2.9.1.

About **typeRoots**: this options was added for backward compatibility support for the [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) and that's why it's not even in the documentation and it's shouldn't be used if you don't use **typings**. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-370019383).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion is working indeed but only thanks to `"include": ["types/**/*.d.ts]"`. I was able to achieve the same by putting `"include": ["src/**/*", "custom_types/custom.d.ts"]`. What I'm trying to figure out here is why TypeScript is ignoring my `typeRoots`

Comment: @anotheruser in your case you have type definitions for global and in my case I had type definitions for a library that I've written in JS so the **paths** is necessary but yes for your case only include should work. If the answer helped you can select it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: @anotheruser btw **typeRoots** was added for backward compatibility support for the [**typings**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) and that's why it's not even in the documentation so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Wait... so that's why I can't find any clear information about this bs that is going on here? Do you have any github discussions or other SO topics to refer to by any chance? Because it sounds like I'm trying to achieve something that I'm should not even try to...

Comment: @anotheruser [Here you go](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-370019383)

Comment: Alright. I guess I’ll have to rethink my approach here. Maybe I’ll just stick to including my type declarations inside `includes`. Thanks for clarification. Please update your answer above by removing `"include": ["types/**/*.d.ts",` so we will not confuse any poor soul that will come here for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to Compile your Typescript file, before you can import in a `js` file.

Example:

```
//test.ts:

const teststring:string="TestThis";
module.exports=teststring+"!";

//run tsc test.ts
//app.js
const testring = require("./test");
console.log(testring);
```

Or you can look here: ['typeRoots' fails to find d.ts declaration files in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287224/typeroots-fails-to-find-d-ts-declaration-files-in-project)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 1) I'm not using typescript (only for type definition). 2) I'm not importing/exporting anything here. I'm  asking why tsconfig is ignoring my custom definitions in the `typeRoots`